# Connection for MS SQL Server with ODBC and XA

Tags: sql-server, odbc, xa

I'm trying to figure out how to get hold of the connection object when using MS SQL Server in an XA context (i.e. using SQL Server as an XA RM)

I'm trying to use xaswitch.lib and build a *resource proxy* and let the TM handle connection (with the OPENINFO string (as the XA specification mandates)) and transactions, but so far I fail to find any API-functions to get hold of this, presumed, already existing connection

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/use-xa-with-dtc?view=sql-server-ver15 seems to be specific for MSDTS and the samples seem to explicitly handling connections and commits/rollbacks rather than with xa_open+xa_close and xa_start+xa_end (tx_begin+tx_commit/tx_rollback) etc

Does anyone have an idea of how to use MS SQL Server in an XA context/environment using ODBC (or some other possible proprietary API) (not JDBC) ?